# can i create a array of special characters in Peoplesoft

Tags: arrays, special-characters, peoplesoft

can i create a array of special characters in Peoplesoft
Something like below.

Local Array of String &MyArray;

&MyArray = CreateArray( "!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work like a charm :)

Did you encountered any issue when executing it ? On my side, no problem when looping on the array and displaying the strings.